# Let $ x_{1} = 8 $ and $ x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} x_n + 2 $ for n = 1, 2, ... . Show {$x_n$} is bounded and monotone, and find its limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $ x_{1} = 8 $ and $ x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} x_n + 2 $ for n = 1, 2, ... . Show {$x_n$} is bounded and monotone, and find its limit.

I know to show that this sequence is bounded, I need to find a convergent subsequence. I see that at n = 4, the sequence is $ 4\frac{1}{2}, 4\frac{1}{4}, 4\frac{1}{8}, 4\frac{1}{16} $ ..., but how do I prove that it is in fact a subsequence that can be written as {$x_n$} = $ 4 + \frac{1}{2^n} $

I do not know how to prove that the sequence is monotonic.

I know that the limit is 4, but I am unsure how to prove it.

Comment: Once you know that the sequence has a limit (see the answer below), to find the actual value of the limit let $\ell=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} x_n$; then, since $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} x_n=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} x_{n+1},$ the limit must satisfy  the recurrence relation $\ell=\frac{\ell}{2}+2,$ that is to say $\ell=4.$

Answer (score 1):

The lower bound of 4 can be shown by a quick induction: if $x_n>4$ then $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}+2>\frac{4}{2}+2=4$, and since $x_1=8>4$ we have $x_n>4$ for all $n$.

Now that we have a lower bound, we can also easily show that $\{x_n\}$ is monotone decreasing:
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{2}x_n+2-x_n=2-\frac{x_n}{2}<2-\frac{4}{2}=0,$$
thus $x_{n+1}<x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown that the sequence is bounded below.

To show that the sequence is monotonic use induction.

Note that $x_2=6<x_1$ and if $x_{n+1}<x_n$ then $x_{n+2}=(1/2)x_{n+1}+2<(1/2)x_n+2=x_{n+1}$
 The limit is $4$ as you have indicated.